# Filtering a Multidimensional Array based of another array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, filter, anonymous-function

I'm creating a PHP class that manipulates csv files.
As part of the class I have a function that allows the data to be filtered `showOnlyWhere`. However I get this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` on line 331 (the line with the `foreach` statement). I tried adding `global $arr;` but that didn't work. How would i fix it?

`$this -> rows` is a multi-dimensional array that contains all the csv data.

`$arr` is in the format:

```
$key=>$val array(
$key = Column Name
$val = value that column should contain
)
```

Below is the `showOnlyWhere` function

```
function showOnlyWhere($arr)
    {

                if($this->showOnlyWhere == true){
                    $rows = $this->filteredRows;
                }
                else{
                    $rows = $this->rows;
                }

                $filter = function ($item){
                        global $arr; // didn't work
                        foreach($arr as $chkCol => $chkVal){
                            if ($item[$arr[$chkCol]] != $chkVal ){
                                return false;
                                break(3);
                            }                      
                        }
                        return true;
                    };


                $this->filteredRows = array_filter($rows,$filter);                  


                $this->showOnlyWhere = true;    
}
```

I think the error might have something to do with the Anonymous function - but I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using `global $arr` you can make `$arr` available to the anonymous function via `use`

```
$filter = function ($item) use ($arr) {
    //global $arr; // didn't work
    foreach($arr as $chkCol => $chkVal){
        if ($item[$arr[$chkCol]] != $chkVal ){
            return false;
        }                      
    }
    return true;
};
```

Also, I noticed that you are assigning `$rows = $this->filteredRows;` before you populate `$this->filteredRows`. I'm not sure if that's intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Format for your $arr is wrong.

this is wrong:

```
$key=>$val array(
$key = Column Name
$val = value that column should contain
)
```

You cannot supply class objects to foreach, it should be a valid array.

It should be like this:

```
$arr=array(
$key => 'Column Name',
$val = 'value that column should contain'
);
```

So first convert your object to a valid array.

Comment: This isn't the asker's actual code, this is poorly formatted pseudo code.  I understand your confusion.